# Django became slow after media root changed

Tags: django

Hi I have a Django project and the media root is in the same drive as the project. But due to disk space problem, I move the it to another drive. But now it became very slow. How do I fix it? Thanks.

Comment: Ideally, it should not really matter. If it is a server instance, try using nginx to server media files. It could increase speed considerably

Answer (score 0):

This should not be a matter when you are launching it on a server, so I should not worry. This might be because you are storing the files in a USB drive, and thats slower to access.